# What else to use other than list of values in a column in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to design a first serious database and I arrived upon a problem. Here's a quick overview – I have event reports in .csv files, which I parse. They contain user card numbers, points and final places. I have no problem filling that data into my database, but I would also like to store in which events the users exist and how many points they have in each of them, instead of just adding up to a total sum of points across all their events.

So I thought I would make a table called `events`, which would have a column `id` (primary key, a_i), `event_name` (to be displayed on frontend next to respective points) and `event_date` (same thing, basically).

The next table would be called `users`, and it would have a column `card_number` (unique key), `total_points` (to display the total sum of all points), `event_ids` and `points`. There lies the problem – I would like to have in the last two columns a list of comma-separated values, which would "tie-in" with each other. Example:

```
`event_ids` = (2, 4, 12, 43)
`points` = (202, 11, 444, 1)
```

So that when I get this info in frontend, I would just loop through these values and get the event_id (which would be the same as `id` in the `events` table) and get all the info I need. However, it seems that list of values in a column in MySQL database is a big NO-NO.

So, how to do this right? I hope you understand my problem, thank you in advance. I'd like to begin with best practices. Any help please? I would like an example..

I'm thinking something like this:

```
user_id   |   event_id   |   points

    3     |      5       |     250
    3     |      12      |     120
    3     |      1       |     200
    3     |      52      |      40
    6     |      2       |     101
    6     |      5       |       3
```

How would I do this?

Comment: How about a `user_events` junction table?

Comment: @Timuçin I don't know a whole lot about junction tables, could anyone please make a bit of a crash course for me?

Comment: At first, a junction table seems a solution but it needs more info. Does an event belong to only one user?

Comment: No, there are multiple users in one event, for example there can be all users in one event or none.

Comment: Never under any circumstance store data in a comma delimited list. This is counterrproductive when you want to query the data. It indicates a need for a related table when you think this is a good idea.

Comment: @HLGEM That is exactly why I came here, to find out how to better do it.

Comment: DO you havea a one to many relationship or a many to many relationship?

Comment: there's many events to many users, so many to many

Comment: please help, I don't know how to do this

Comment: @user3647430 create table `event_users` and add these columns: event_id, user_id, points (same as what u placed at last paragraph ). I really don't get what your database is for, but I think this will give some help.